# How to extract the value of TIME(7) field of MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 in java?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion, apache-metamodel

I am using `Apache Meta-model` to extract the values from `MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2` database. There is a field in `MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2` database of type `TIME(7)` whose java equivalent type is `java.sql.Time` but `java.sql.Time` is NOT showing the milliseconds. e.g.

```
Actual `TIME(7)` value in database: `12:28:16.9475678`
whereas I getting: `12:28:16`
```

How to get the Time in milliseconds?

Updated:

When I tried to get milliseconds using `org.joda.time.LocalTime` as you can see below:

```
   LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(((Time)row.getValues()[pos]).getTime());
   localTime.toString();
```

Output: `12:28:16.947` (It showing the round value of `9475678`)

After converting it to `String`, I am getting the round value of      milliseconds `12:28:16.947`. The millisecond precision is lost.
**Please suggest how to get the the exact value in millisecond without rounding value?**

> Updated:

I tried using getNanos() as suggested,but i am getting zero milliseconds except my exact millisecond value like:

**actual value: 12:28:16.9475678 and i am getting 12:28:16.9470000**

code:-

```
 long timestamp =new Timestamp(((Time)row.getValues()[pos]).getTime()).getNanos();
```

Answer (score 2):

[java.sql.Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) doesn't include milliseconds.  Try using [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead, as that will include the fractional seconds.

Comment: I tried it with `org.joda.time.LocalTime` and it automatic rounding the milliseconds value.

Comment: @shree using `LocalTime` is not going to help you, because you will still first get the `java.sql.Time`. Get it as timestamp (you may need to convert/cast to timestamp in your query first(!)), and also look at [`Timestamp.getNanos()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getNanos--) which contains the fractional seconds in nanoseconds.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. I will give it  try and Let you know.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel.I tried Timestamp.getNanos(),it gives me lost value after three digits and append zero in place of actual values as mentioned above

Comment: I see you're still casting it to java.sql.Time before passing it to the Timestamp constructor.  My knowledge of java.sql.Time is out of date, it does in fact support milliseconds, but not nanoseconds.  This is why you are only getting milliseconds.
Check the type being returned by "row.getValues()[pos]".  If it's a Timestamp then cast it as that to maintain the nanoseconds.  If it's a Time then there is nothing you can do, the nanoseconds are not available to you.